# Can't login with the correct credentials of a user created from admin panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I created a UserController where admin can create a user with special privileges, asides from the Laravel Automatic register page, the issue is user creation works fine via the UserController but I can't sign in with the details I used when creating the account. Would appreciate any help I can find on here.

```
public function create()
    {
        //
        $privileges = privilege::all();
        $courses = course::all();
        return view('tutor.create')->with('privileges', $privileges)->with('courses',$courses);
    }
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',

        ]);
            $users = new User;
            $users->name = $request->input('name');
            $users->email = $request->input('email');
            $users->password = \Hash::make($request['password']);
            $users->privilege_id = $request->input('privilege_id');
            $users->save();
            $course = $request->get('course');
            $users->courses()->attach($course);
            return redirect('/tutor')->with('success','User created');
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me your login code?

Comment: I am currently using Laravel's authentication.

Comment: I don't understand your question @Mahmood Sanjrani

Comment: Dear, I mean to say that are you using same server/machine when you created user or have you changed your server/machine?
have you moved your code when you created user?

Comment: I am using thesame machine for both process. @Mahmood Sanjrani